# Determining Big-O complexity

Tags: c, big-o

I have some code below with a nested while loop. I figured complexity of the outer while loop, but I am not sure how to do so for the inner one is as it has an `&&`. Can someone explain to me how to determine the complexity for the inner loop?

```
int result = 0;
int i = 0;
while (i < n / 2){                // O(log N)
    result += arr[i];
    i += 1;
    while (i >= n / 2 && i < n){  //Not sure how the parameters change it. O(log N) ? 
        result += arr[i];
        i += 1;
    }
}
printf("%d\n", result);
```

Comment: This looks like a job for ComputerScience.StackExchange.

Comment: Why do you think the first `while` loop is `log N`? You're multiplying `n` by `1/2`, not taking its log (nor continually or recursively halving `n`).

Comment: In other words, this whole thing can be replaced by a single loop, `while ( i < n )`...

Comment: Indeed, someone is being played here. And it's working :-)

Answer (score 4):

The outer loop increments until i = (n / 2) - 1. The next i += 1 puts it at i = n / 2 and then the inner loop runs until i = n. The outer loop does not do another iteration.

The following would be equivalent.

```
while (i < n / 2){
    result += arr[i];
    i += 1;    
}
// i = n / 2
while (i < n){
    result += arr[i];
    i += 1;
}
```

O(n) + O(n) = O(n)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way of writing your code:

```
int result = 0;
int i = 0;
while (i < n) {
    result += arr[i++];
}
printf("%d\n", result);
```

so it's clearly O(n), or linear, time.